# Order by clause within the Set of an Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pick the top 1 result from a select statement inside the set statement of an Update. I can pick the top 1 but the order by clause does not work. Is there a way to make it work or a workaround please?

```
UPDATE  a1
SET     a1.ServiceLength = ( SELECT TOP 1
                                    a3.START_DATE
                                    ORDER BY  a3.START_DATE DESC
                         )
FROM    #t a1
    JOIN #TempService a2 ON a1.EmployeeNo = a2.EMPLOYEE_NO
    JOIN #TempService a3 ON a3.EMPLOYEE_NO = a2.Employee_No
WHERE   a2.START_DATE = a3.END_DATE + 1
    AND @specifiedDate > a2.START_DATE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this using a CTE:

```
WITH TopDate  
AS
(
   SELECT TOP 1 a3.START_DATE, a3.employee_no 
   FROM   #t a1 
   JOIN #tempservice a2 ON a1.employeeno = a2.employee_no 
   JOIN #tempservice a3 ON a3.employee_no = a2.employee_no 
   WHERE  a2.start_date = a3.end_date + 1 
       AND @specifiedDate > a2.start_date
   ORDER BY  a3.START_DATE DESC
)
UPDATE  a1
SET a1.ServiceLength = t.START_DATE
FROM #t a1
INNER JOIN TopDate AS t ON a1.employeeno = t.employee_no
```

Comment: i copied exact sql that you provided, it's throwing me the following error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @user1490835 - Try `;WITH TopDate ...` also what version of sql server you are using? This should work fine for SQL Server 2005 +

Comment: Thanks Mate. With a couple of workarounds, i got it working the way i wanted. Thanks for your help again. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MAX(START_DATE) to get the latest START_DATE for each employee

```
update A set A.ServiceLength= (select MAX(B.Start_Date) from #tbl1 B where  B.EmployeeNo=A.EmployeeNo)
from #tbl1 A
```

Please add necessary where clause for your query.

Comment: This and the answer from Mahmoud helped me to get where i wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...:

```
UPDATE a1 
SET    a1.servicelength = a3.start_date                          
FROM #t a1 
       JOIN #tempservice a2 
         ON a1.employeeno = a2.employee_no 
       JOIN (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_NO ORDER BY START_DATE DESC) AS rnk
             FROM #tempservice) a3 
         ON a3.employee_no = a2.employee_no
         AND a3.rnk = 1      
WHERE  a2.start_date = a3.end_date + 1 
       AND @specifiedDate > a2.start_date
```

Comment: it first says incorrect syntax near the *, when i remove the *, it says incorrect syntax near the Over?